# Python string interpolation for string and dictionary in the same line

Tags: python, dictionary, string-interpolation

I have a dictionary and a datetime object I converted to string. How do I print the datetime string and several items from the dictionary in the same line?

For example:

```
dictionary = {"_source": {"host": "host", "type": "type"}}
datetime = '25-08-2017 10:26:11'
```

This is what I'm trying to print:

```
print("%s %(host)s %(type)s" % (datetime,dictionary["_source"]))
```

Getting an error on the datetime string:

```
TypeError: format requires a mapping
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add what do you what for output for this example? Is it '25-08-2017 10:26:11 host type'?

Comment: Here's how you would do it using `format`: `print("{0} {1[host]} {1[type]}".format(datetime,dictionary["_source"]))`  Read more about `format` [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have said it is probably the best to use [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). The closest option with method [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to your question is code which 
[Violet Red](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8370836/violet-red) suggested in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45885146/6476044):

```
"{} {host} {type}".format(datetime,**dictionary["_source"])
```

But if you really want or need to use the old way of formatting (using `%`) then you can try some of these options:

- **Separating string into two or more strings**

  Like [Eugene Yarmash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244297/eugene-yarmash) explained in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45885233/6476044) you can't mix ordinary and mapping format specifiers in same string, but you could separate it to two (or more) strings like this:

  ```
  '%s' % datetime + ' %(type)s %(host)s' % dictionary["_source"]
  ```

  This will work but if you wanted to print `datetime` in the middle (something like this `'%(type)s %s %(host)s'`) or if you have more ordinary and mapping format specifiers which are intertwined (something like this `'%s '%(type)s %s %(host)s' %s`). You could separate `'%(type)s %s %(host)s'` into multiple strings like this:

  ```
  '%(type)s' % dictionary["_source"] + ' %s ' % datetime +  '%(host)s' % dictionary["_source"]
  ```

  But then there is no point in string format in first place.
- **First applying mapping than ordinary format specifiers**

  This method solves our problem of formatting string with ordinary and mapping format specifiers which are intertwined. I will explain this method on the example from OP. We have string `'%s %(type)s %(host)s'` which we want to format. Like I said in first we apply mapping format specifiers:

  ```
  print('%s %(type)s %(host)s' % dictionary["_source"])
  ```

  If we do this it will print out:

  ```
  '{'type': 'type', 'host': 'host'} type host'
  ```

  This does not work, but what we can do is add parentheses `()` in every ordinary format specifier and update our dictionary with `{'': '%s'}`:

  ```
  print('%()s %(type)s %(host)s' % {'type': 'type', 'host': 'host', '': '%s'})
  ```

  This will print out:

  `'%s type host'`

  which we can easily format with `% (datetime)`.

  The question is how to `{'': '%s'}` to your dictionary. You have two options, to use a function or to define your class for the dictionary object.

  **1. Using function**

  ```
  def ForFormat(x):
      d = x.copy()
      d.update({'': '%s'})
      return d
  ```

  And you use it like this:

  ```
  print('%()s %(type)s %(host)s' % ForFormat(dictionary["_source"]) % (datetime))
  ```

  The result is exactly what we want:

  ```
  '25-08-2017 10:26:11 type 45 host'
  ```

  **2. Creating class**

  ```
  class FormatDict(dict):
      def __missing__(self, key):
          return '%s'
  ```

  Here we don't actually add `{'': '%s'}` to dictionary, but rather change its method `__missing__()` which is called when key can not be found in dictionary so it will retrun `'%s'` for each mapping format specifier that is not in dictionary. It is used like this:

  ```
  print('%()s %(type)s %(host)s' % FormatDict(dictionary["_source"]) % (datetime))
  ```

  It also prints out the desired result:

  ```
  '25-08-2017 10:26:11 type 45 host'
  ```

Answer (score 6):

One way is to assign a name to your datetime arg:

```
"{t} {host} {type}".format(t=datetime,**dictionary["_source"])
```

But actually it will work even without it

```
"{} {host} {type}".format(datetime,**dictionary["_source"])
```

though it's better to use named values in formatted strings imo

Answer (score 3):

You're better off using the [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) method:

```
>>> "{} {d[host]} {d[type]}".format(datetime, d=dictionary["_source"])
'25-08-2017 10:26:11 host type'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix ordinary and mapping format specifiers in a single format string. You should use either

```
"%s %s %s" % (param1, param2, param3)
```

or

```
"%(key1)s %(key2)s %(key3)s" % {"key1": val1, "key2": val2, "key3": val3}
```

In Python 3.6+ you can use much more convenient and efficient [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) for interpolation, e.g:

```
f'{val1} {val2} {val3}'
```

where replacement fields are *expressions* evaluated at run time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
dictionary = {"_source": {"host": "host", "type": "type"}}
datetime = '25-08-2017 10:26:11'

print("host {} type {} datetime {}".format(dictionary["_source"]["host"], dictionary["_source"]["type"], datetime))
```